# Generate rows of interest payments according to monthly/yearly payment rate?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table which consists of the fixed principal value, the start and end dates, the interest rate (percentage), and either "Monthly" or "Yearly", depending on the agreed payment rate. This table is showing the amount of interest to be paid monthly/yearly for a given amount of time on an interest rate calculated on the principal value.

What I need to do is to generate x rows, where x is the number of interest payments made, each one showing the amount paid for that payment. So if for example I have a 2% interest rate on a sum of 1000 for a year, using monthly payments this would generate 12 rows containing 2% of 1000 each.

Any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: Are you talking about an *investment* with compounded interest here (principal increases), or payments made on *loan* (principal decreases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has a multitude of built-in financial functions.  I'm assuming you're talking about an investment with compounded interest here.  If instead, you're talking about paying off a *loan*, I'll have to come back and rewrite this.

The simplest way to do this is by using Excel's future value function FV().  In the picture below, the first two rows show the terms of the investment.  The second table shows the results of the investment, which can be calculated in a couple of different ways.

[image]

The Future Value column is calculated using FV(rate,nper,pmt,pv,type).  You specify the interest rate, principal and number of periods.  Type this formula in B5 and fill down.

```
=FV(D$2/12,A5,0,-A$2)
```

The yearly interest rate of 2% has to be divided by 12 here since we're calculating the accrued interest each month. A5:A16 hold the number of payment periods. There are no periodic payments *into* the investment so the next term is 0.  And finally the principal is entered as a negative number. (There are some oddball conventions for these formulas.  The negative sign indicates the original principal was paid *out* into the bank or investment).

Now it's easy to calculate the interest payment each month. By subtracting $1000 (the original principal) from the first month's FV, we see that it increased by $1.67, which is the amount of the first interest payment. Subtracting the previous month's FV from subsequent months generates the interest payments in column C.

But there is also a way to calculate the payments in one step.  The Interest Payment function does this - IPMT(rate,per,nper,pv,fv,type).  Column C was calculated using this formula:

```
=IPMT(D$2/12,A5,F$2,-A$2,FV(D$2/12,F$2,0,-A$2))
```

You can get fancy and figure the interest rate differently based on whether the interest is specified as Monthly or Yearly:

```
=IPMT(IF(E$2="Yearly",D$2/12,D$2),A5,F$2,-A$2,FV(IF(E$2="Yearly",D$2/12,D$2),F$2,0,-A$2))
```

And you can calculate the number of periods from the start and end dates by typing this in F2:

```
=(YEAR(C2)-YEAR(B2))*12+MONTH(C2)-MONTH(B2)+1
```

I hope this helps, and I *SURE* hope you meant to ask about an investment rather than a loan.  Good luck!

Comment: This was **exactly** what I was looking for. A thorough and detailed answer I actually enjoyed reading. You have my thanks Sir, this answer has saved me a lot of work and headaches, while teaching me the power of Excel. Peace!